# Prove that $S^{1}$ is homeomorphic to $S^{1}/\sim$ where $a \sim b$ if and only if $a$ and $b$ are the two endpoints of a diameter of $S^{1}$

Tags: general-topology

Given that $a \sim b$ if and only if $a$ and $b$ are the two endpoints of a diameter of $S^{1}$. $S^{1}$ is homeomorphic to $S^{1}/\sim$.

I know I need to first start by constructing a map $f: S^{1} \rightarrow S^{1}$, such that $x \sim x' \implies f(x)=f(x')$, which would then imply that $\phi: S^{1}/\sim \ \rightarrow S^{1}$ is continuous. Then construct a candidate inverse function $\psi:S^{1} \rightarrow S^{1}/\sim$, then show that their (right and left) composition are the identity maps.

But I'm having trouble constructing the initial map $f$. Can any one give me some sort of direction here?

Comment: $f(\cos x,\sin x)=(\cos 2x,\sin 2x)$. In the complex numbers, $f(z)=z^2$.

Comment: Right, so basically, since the 2 ends of the diameter are separated by $\pi$. Squaring them just gives us a $2\pi$ term, which is nothing but the period of $\cos$ and $\sin$, hence giving us the same functional value.